# Trying to add delay and only on click expansion to menu.js

Tags: magento-2.1, topmenu

Currently when hovering over the topmenu the menu expands instantly, and other topics seem to not give insight that help my case.
I want to either add delay or to expand the menu only on click.
Any changes in menu.js seem to not even respond to changes on the website.

Here's the code of menu.js that should be relevant

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "matchMedia",
    "jquery/ui",
    "jquery/jquery.mobile.custom",
    "mage/translate"
], function ($, mediaCheck) {
    'use strict';

/**
 * Menu Widget - this widget is a wrapper for the jQuery UI Menu
 */
$.widget('mage.menu', $.ui.menu, {
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        expanded: false,
        delay: 300

    },
```

Comment: did you get the solution ?

Comment: No, it still expands instantly

Comment: could your share your site URL , I need to check ..it can be fixed via CSS

Comment: http://safegear.com/

Comment: I can add delay and it will open smoothly... if this works for you , then I ll post the code

Comment: are you using _extend.less  in your custom theme ?

Comment: only _extends.less

Comment: see _extends.less usage mentioned here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588

Comment: Maybe menu options are overwritten in .phtml template?

Comment: Manoj has solved the problem, works perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Some **CSS tweaks to open menu smoothly with some delay** rather than instantly

**To add custom CSS/LESS always better to use `_extend.less`**

See detailed answer for using `_extend.less` https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588

Now in your `_extend.less` paste below css code

```
.page-header.header-newskin .navigation li.level0.fullwidth .submenu {
    transform-origin: top;
    webkit-transform: scale(1,0);
   -ms-transform: scale(1,0);
   transform: scale(1,0);
   -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out 0s;
   transition: all 600ms ease-in-out 0s;



}

.sw-megamenu.navigation li.level0.fullwidth:hover > .submenu {
   webkit-transform:scale(1,1);
   -ms-transform: scale(1,1);
   transform: scale(1,1);
}
```

Then run the commands mentioned here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588

Hopefully this should work for you

Comment: Again, you hit it on the head! I will customize the css to fit my website, but thanks for giving me a solution!

Comment: Cheers ! Always use extend less for custom css