# How to change color of cart icon in minicart?

Tags: magento2, css, less

I am trying to **change color of cart icon** in header/minicart , as currently it's in **grey shade**

[image]

I tried changing via adding following css in my `custom.css` at `\web\css\custom.css`

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart::before{
   color:#fe0404;
}
```

but some how it's not working

Comment: You just need to deploy and cache clean. If still output not display then check it in private browser

Comment: your changes looks fine, just deploy the code and check

Comment: try placing css in your extended module , so it will overwrite the module css. in your custom css it might not work because of the order of CSS, you can use important but this is not right practice

Comment: how can I change in module css? do I have to extend each module for changing css of respective .... yes it works with important ...but I don't want to use that for each changes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Adding your custom CSS/LESS or updating existing CSS/LESS** use  **_extend.less** .

This will load first so there will no issue of `css order` and you will not require using `important`

Create this at below location

```
app\design\frontend\vendor-name\theme-name\Magento_Theme\web\css\source\_extend.less
```

**Place all your custom CSS and LESS** in `_extend.less` . It's better to use LESS , so you can use variables or mixins  for better management.

Run below commands after placing your CSS/LESS

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Keep your cache disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple.

Open the file:
*app/design/frontend/**[YOUR_VENDOR]**/**[YOUR_THEME]**/web/css/source/_theme.less*

Look for the variable **@minicart-icons-color** and set the color you want for the mini cart icon.

If the variable does not exist, just add it.

Example:

[image]

Now compile your theme!

Here is the minicart icon lib:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: still not working