# How to change color of specific element of applied theme

Tags: magento-2.0

How to change the color of the specific font, element of the applied theme in Magento2 on the server. Is it is required to open theme file and then edit, or there are some other alternatives?

Comment: Have a look in to the following post,  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195703/how-to-change-color-of-cart-icon-in-minicart

Answer (score 1):

Generally, paid theme providers provide the option to change the font, color and font size etc. from settings in the admin panel, but the default Magento's Luma or Blank themes do not provide such option.

In case, there is no option in the settings, you need to make changes in the files.

It is recommended that you should register your custom theme, apply that theme and create a _extend.less file and put there your custom rules.

To know more about creating custom theme and writing custom css rules, please check the URL:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want to change small elements of an existing Magento theme, you have to create your custom theme, inheriting from the existing theme, and just add your custom classes.

If your changes are minimal, as suggested in the question that @MAGento suggested you, you just have to register your custom theme and create an _extend.less file and put there your custom rules

Just follow the official guide http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html