# Magento 2 - How I can move the limiter at the top

Tags: magento2, toolbar

how I can **move limiter from bottom to top toolbar**.

I check the code in console and at the top toolbar already exist but is hidden, how I can do to see this at the top.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: did you get the solution , worked for you ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**To Turn on Limiter in top toolbar** add below css in  `_extend.less`   in your **custom theme module**

```
.page-products .toolbar .limiter {
    display: block;
}
```

**To Hide in bottom toolbar**

```
.products.wrapper ~ .toolbar .limiter {
    display: none;
}
```

[For Adding your custom CSS/LESS or updating existing CSS/LESS use _extend.less](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588)

**Run commands mentioned in above link** to make custom css work for you

I hope this will help you out if any problem then let me know.

Comment: I also used the same way , and worked perfect :)

Comment: is okay thank you

Comment: Sounds good to hear that , cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Its already there but is hidden via css. Just change the following css class to

```
.page-products .toolbar .limiter {
    display: block;
}
```

and hide the one on the bottom via css.
Top and bottom toolbar are the same template

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list\toolbar.phtml
```

Elements are shown or hidden via css.