# How to change product hover effect?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, grid, css

**I want to change hover effect on mouse over in product list**

Which files do I need to edit for the same ?

Comment: does it helped you ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of cart icon in minicart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195703/how-to-change-color-of-cart-icon-in-minicart)

Answer (score 1):

Inspect in your browser and you will get your code . Like below sample from luma theme.

`.products-grid .product-item-info:hover{}`

[image]

[You can see detailed answer of how to change CSS / LESS in magento way](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588)

This should help you out and others as well.