# Remove disable button opacity from search form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, javascript, search

I've create a new theme based on Blank theme. The **search button** is **transparent** when there is no text in the input.

How can I remove that transparency?

```
        <div class="control">
            <input id="search"
                   data-mage-init='{"quickSearch":{
                        "formSelector":"#search_mini_form",
                        "url":"<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getUrl('search/ajax/suggest', ['_secure' => $block->getRequest()->isSecure()]) ?>",
                        "destinationSelector":"#search_autocomplete"}
                   }'
                   type="text"
                   name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $helper->getQueryParamName() ?>"
                   value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $helper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>"
                   placeholder="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Search entire store here...') ?>"
                   class="input-text"
                   maxlength="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $helper->getMaxQueryLength() ?>"
                   role="combobox"
                   aria-haspopup="false"
                   aria-autocomplete="both"
                   autocomplete="off"/>
            <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <button type="submit"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Search')) ?>"
                class="action search">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('GO') ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

In frontend on the search button I have this `disabled=""`; Maybe this is the problem?

```
<div class="actions">
<button class="action search" type="submit" title="Search" disabled="">
<span>GO</span>
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple `CSS` change you need to do, add below CSS in your custom or **extended CSS file**.

**By default opacity for disabled state is 0.5** , you need to change it to "**1**"

```
.block-search .actions.search[disabled]{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

[You can check here detailed answer of  how to add custom CSS / LESS in Magento Way](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588)

**Note:** Above changes tested on LUMA THEME

Comment: is okay thanks, the only thing in your answer is that the .action div is .actions

Comment: I updated your suggestion @Robert , Cheers ! , however ".action " class is used in button and ".actions" in parent div in which button is placed . Any way this helped you so that's good.